# PHP curl_exec returning partial response

Tags: php, curl

I have set up a php program that calls a RESTful web service using curl and gets back well-formed XML. When I do this on th e command line and I get the correct response but when I do this in PHP using `curl_exec()` I only get about half of the response. The response is basically cut short.

Does anyone know the cause of this?

Code is as follows:

```
       $url = $this->dspace_url . '/dspace/search.xml?query=' . urlencode($query);
       $sac_curl = curl_init();
       error_log('query url is'.$url);
       curl_setopt($sac_curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
       curl_setopt($sac_curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($sac_curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
       curl_setopt($sac_curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt($sac_curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
       $resp = curl_exec($sac_curl);            
       error_log('response is '.$resp);
```

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: is CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER on?

Comment: Show some of the curl code. The issue may be a SET_OPT.

Comment: which php version are you using?

Comment: I am using php version 5.2.11

Comment: Since it's a GET, what happens if you hit the url directly in a browser?

Comment: Hitting the URL with the browser gets the complete response. I also tried removing the GET option and I still get a partial response.

Comment: What's the difference between `$curl` and `$sac_curl`? If you're modifying the code for stackoverflow (which is laudable, don't get me wrong), please copy the important parts verbatim.

Comment: sorry that was typo - it should be $sac_curl - fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the `error_log` function to save your response to the error log.

There seems to be a limit on this (defaults to 1024 bytes) but you can change it in your php.ini file using the `log_errors_max_len` attribute. Try setting that to something larger and see if you find any difference.

Comment: Thanks Jaitsu - yes my code was working but I was seeing only partial XML due to the limit on error_log - doh!