# PHP CURL Retrieves Partial pages

Tags: php, html, curl, web-crawler

I have the following CURL code:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
if ($postParameters != '') {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postParameters);
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, __DIR__.'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, __DIR__.'/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
$pageResponse = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

When I try to fetch pages, most of the time I get the entire page I asked for. However, from time to time I will get only parts of the page, for example:

> DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
>   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> html
>   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en"> head>
>     meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;
>   charset=windows-1251" /> meta name="generator" content="

I removed the "<" in front of the tags so the HTML code would be displayed on stack exchange.
Does anybody knows why it suddenly stops receiving? I noticed that the data often abruptly stops after an open double quotes (i.e. content="  or username="). Not sure 100% if it always happens that way. In any case, could this be an encoding issue? 
Any other ideas?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263066/php-curl-exec-returning-partial-response can help. Otherwise, does this happen on multiple websites? It might be a problem on their end if it only happens with one website.

Comment: Depending on your use case you may be able to just use `file_get_contents()` and dispense with curl.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add some debugging.

Add these options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR,$f = fopen(__DIR__ . "/error.log", "w+"));
```

And these before curl_close():

```
if($errno = curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
    echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
}
```

If that doesn't work try increasing the timeout and see if it goes away:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
```

If the timeout increase works, then find out why.